# Capacitor Voltage during Transients

Tags: capacitor, resistors, dc, differential, transient

I am starting to learn transient analysis series RC which requires our own equations to be derived, but I don't understand how the voltage across the capacitor is given in the equation below from a KVL loop around the circuit (underlined in yellow):

[image]

[image]

I'm assuming it comes from the basic capacitor voltage/current relationship formula below, but would appreciate if someone would explain how it is given in this form mathematically.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you want us to derive it? because this looks like a homework problem and homework problems need an attempt at a solution.

Comment: It's from my theory notes and I'm just unsure where it came from, as I've never seen it before. I am happy deriving it myself, if someone could just confirm if it comes from the basic voltage/current capacitor relationship I posted above?

Comment: Yeah, it comes from integrating the capacitor current, this will yield a voltage function. You plug that in KVL equation for the capacitor voltage and you get what you show in your question.

Comment: Integrate both sides of \$i = C \frac{dv}{dt}\$ over time and you get \$\int i \, dt + i_0 = C\, v\$.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: Ok, think I have it. But in the equation highlighted in my question above, is it assuming that the capacitor voltage is initially at 0 volts, hence not taking             Vc (at t = 0) into account?

Comment: @David777 As I'm sure you already know, there are initial conditions needed to resolve constants of integration. So, you do need to know some condition at some moment in time to pin down the position of the resulting curve. Usually, if unstated and no other hints are present, the only assumption you can easily defend is that at the start (which is, again, probably *assumed* to be at \$t=0\$), the voltage on the capacitor (and it's stored charge) are assumed zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions aren't entirely clear to me, so please accept my apologies if I wander just a bit. I'll avoid using integrating factors below, as well, since it's not necessary for this problem.

For ideal capacitors (few are), the basic idea is \$Q=C\:V\$. Taking the full derivative, this is \$\text{d} Q = C\:\text{d} V+V\:\text{d}C\$. But it's usually assumed that \$\text{d}C=0\$ -- that there is no change in capacitance, since it is a fixed value in an ideal capacitor. So \$\text{d} Q = C\:\text{d} V\$. You can now introduce time by simply dividing both sides by \$\text{d} t\$, giving \$\frac{\text{d} Q}{\text{d} t} = C\:\frac{\text{d} V}{\text{d} t}=I\$. (The ad-hoc introduction of the infinitesimal of time can be done where it pleases.)

Your KVL loop equation is:

$$\begin{align*}
V &= R\:I_{\left(t\right)}+\frac{1}{C}\int I_{\left(t\right)}\:\text{d}t\tag{1}\\\\
\text{d} V&=R\:\text{d}I_{\left(t\right)}+\frac{I_{\left(t\right)}}{C}\text{d} t=0\tag{2}\\\\
\text{d}I_{\left(t\right)}&=-\frac{I_{\left(t\right)}}{R\,C}\text{d} t\tag{3}\\\\
\frac{\text{d}I_{\left(t\right)}}{I_{\left(t\right)}}&=\frac{-1}{R\,C}\text{d} t\tag{4}\\\\
\int\frac{\text{d}I_{\left(t\right)}}{I_{\left(t\right)}}&=\frac{-1}{R\,C}\int\text{d} t\tag{5}\\\\
\operatorname{ln}\left(I_{\left(t\right)}\right)&=\frac{-t}{R\,C} + A_0\tag{6}\\\\
I_{\left(t\right)}&=e^{\left[\frac{-t}{R\,C} + A_0\right]}=e^{A_0}e^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}=A\,e^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}\tag{7}
\end{align*}$$

Where \$A\$ is the constant of integration you need to worry about, now. At \$t=0\$, it must be that \$A=I_{t=0}\$. If the voltage across the capacitor at \$t=0\$ is \$V_C=0\:\text{V}\$, then it follows that \$A=\frac{V}{R}\$. So the result must be:

$$I_{\left(t\right)}=\frac{V}R\,e^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}\tag{Series Current}\label{E1}$$

And,

$$\begin{align*}
V_{C\left(t\right)} &= \frac{1}{C}\int I_{\left(t\right)}\:\text{d}t\tag{8}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{C}\int \frac{V}R\,e^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}\:\text{d}t\tag{9}\\\\
&=\frac{V}{R\,C}\int e^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}\:\text{d}t\tag{10}\\\\
&=\frac{V}{R\,C}\left[-R\,C\,e^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}} + A_0\right]\tag{11}\\\\
&=V\left[\frac{A_0}{R\,C}-e^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}\right]\tag{12}
\end{align*}$$

Again, at \$t=0\$ and assuming that \$V_{C\left(t=0\right)}=0\:\text{V}\$, it follows that \$A_0=R\,C\$. So:

$$V_{C\left(t\right)}=V\left[1-e^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}\right]\label{E2}\tag{Capacitor Voltage}$$

That's it. The \$\ref{E1}\$ equation provides the current in both \$R\$ and \$C\$, since both must be the same. The \$\ref{E2}\$ equation provides the voltage that accumulates onto the capacitor over time.

Comment: jonk, how do you enter the maths equations in the form you have in your answer?

Comment: @David777 I use Latex (kind of.) It's actually [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) -- click that link for examples.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer by the way. The maths with the diff equations is causing me the issues, not the circuit analysis part. I will do some work with deriving equations.

Comment: @David777 If you select one or two that are troublesome, let me try and help explain them better. I'll tag them to make it a little easier for you to name them.

Comment: I am unsure how you get from equation 5 to 6. Where does the -t come from on the top line? And what is Ao for?

Comment: I understand the natural log by the way, just not the right hand side of equation 5

Comment: @David777 Whenever you do an indefinite integral, there is a constant of integration and needs to be solved, somehow, with known initial conditions. In integrating both sides of (4) to get (5), there must be a constant of integration for each integral. No need for two of them, though. So I just put it on the right side as \$A_0\$. I could have put it on the left side. But I chose the right. Either way it is the same thing. I assumed you already knew that \$\int \text{d}t=t\$ and since there was already a -1 there, it should be clear where the -t comes from. Isn't it?

Comment: Ah so adding + Ao as the constant is the same as what I have learned by just adding + c after integrating?

Comment: @David777 Yes. I just chose to use \$A_0\$ instead of \$C\$ because of the possible confusion with the capacitance. In doing so, I see I caused confusion. Sorry about that.

Comment: Haha ok, I understand that part now, thank you. Also does the e to the power of come from taking the integral of ln (i) in equation 7?

Comment: @David777 The integral on the left side of (5) is solved as ln(). I then raised both sides of (6) as the power of e in order to get rid of the ln() function to get (7).

Comment: Thank you jonk, this has solved all of my questions about this series RC circuit.

Comment: @David777 Glad to hear it. I've used semi-unconventional calculus (more unconventional for formalist mathematicians, but not at all unconventional for physicists.) For example, I used a differential operator to get from (1) to (2) and in the paragraph above (1). The idea of treating \$\text{d} x\$ as a variable that can be cancelled, divided into, multiplied by, etc -- no different as in any algebraic context for a young student -- didn't receive mathematical justification until 1964 (I think) with Abraham Robinson's "Non-Standard Analysis" but was used by Newton's fluxions, centuries earlier.

Comment: Sorry jonk, can you explain the steps of how you get from equation 11 to 12, and then to the final capacitor voltage equation? Thanks again.

Comment: @David777 Well, getting from (11) to (12) should be simple algebra. The RC cancels in the first term of the second factor because of the denominator of the first factor. And I just moved \$A_0\$ to the front and, of course, again applied the first factor's denominator to it, as I should. Just basic algebra there. The final equation had to apply initial conditions to figure out \$A_0\$. But that just turns out to be \$R\:C\$ because to force the equation to produce 0 volts at time 0, that term had to become a "1" somehow. That "somehow" is by setting \$A_0=R\:C\$.

Comment: jonk, sorry to bother you again, but could you explain the steps you took on equation number 7 please? Specifically how you get (e^Ao) and then just A.   Thanks

Comment: @David777 \$e^{A_0}\$ is a constant raised to a constant power. That's the same thing as ... just another constant. No point in keeping it complicated-looking. So I just replaced the constant \$e^{A_0}\$ by the constant \$A\$. (\$A=e^{A_0}\$.) Makes no difference, at all.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is after switch closes, Ip=V/R then decays with a slope dV/dt=V/RC = V/T then exponential decay. So Vc rises with this slope with same exponential rise toward Vc with a linear asymptote at the t=T=RC at V=~64%Vcc then slower as current reduces.